# What are some of the sutra's related to the Twelve Links (Nidanas)?

Tags: reference-request, nidanas

Jarāmaranam,
Jāti,
Bhava,
Upādāna,
Tanhā,
Vedanā,
Phassa,
Salāyatana,
Nāma-rūpa,
Viññāna,
Sankhārā,
Avidya.

I believe they operate inversely and wanted to see further how this inversion is illustrated in the Pali canon.

Answer (score 2):

The best survey of suttas on Twelve Nidanas that I have seen can be found in "[The Fundamental Teachings of Early Buddhism: A comparative study based on the Sutranga portion of the Pali Samyutta-Nikaya and the Chinese Samyuktagama](https://ahandfulofleaves.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/the-fundamental-teachings-of-early-buddhism_choong-mun-keat.pdf)" by Choong Mun-keat.

Comment: Thank you. This is very detailed and informative study.

Answer (score 1):

There's an entire samyutta on the Nidanas in the Connected Discourses: https://suttacentral.net/sn12

Comment: Great. Thank you. Suttacentral has a nice app too.